# Func<HttpRequestMessage> related Mocking Questions for Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am using Moq in my XUnit test. In the dependency methods, it contains a `Func<HttpResponseMessage>` parameter. Here's the unit test that I wrote:

```
      [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var content = new StringContent(TestData.GetResponse().ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = content
        };
        _mockRetryHttpRequest.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<HttpRequestMessage>>(), It.IsAny<HttpClient>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
                           .ReturnsAsync(httpResponse);
        var libraryService = new LibraryService(_mockRetryHttpRequest.Object);

        //Act
        var response = await libraryService.GetResponseForSearch(new SearchRequest(), null);

        //Assert
        response.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
```

And here's the actual method that I need to test on

```
public class LibraryService : ILibraryService
{
    private IRetryHttpRequest _retryHttpRequest;
    public LibraryService(IRetryHttpRequest retryHttpRequest)
    {
        _retryHttpRequest = retryHttpRequest;
    }


    public async Task<ResponseModel> GetResponseForSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest, HttpClient client)
    {
        //send request and retry if failed
        ResponseModel result = new ResponseModel();
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => new HttpRequestMessage(), client, 3);

        //process response
        if (httpResponseMessage != null)
        {
            string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class RetryHttpRequest : IRetryHttpRequest
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(Func<HttpRequestMessage> requestMessage, HttpClient client, int maxTryValue)
    {
        var content = new StringContent("From Execute Async", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = content
        };
        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

When I stepped through the code, for this below line of code, the `httpResponseMessage` variable is returning `null` despite the fact that I already mocked it with 200 response in the unit test.

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => new HttpRequestMessage(), client, 3);
```

Comment: I think you should be awaiting it in act like `var response = await lgService.GetResponse`

Comment: @CodingYoshi still doesn't fix the issue :(

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the `Returns` part of the mock and see if it gets hit.

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes it does

Comment: Are you sure we're talking about the same thing? It has to hit `Task.FromResult(httpResponse)`. Please confirm if it does.

Comment: @CodingYoshi hmm, the whole line is `_mockRetryHttpRequest.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync(() => It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<HttpClient>()))
                         .Returns(Task.FromResult(httpResponse));` and `Task.FromResult` is part of the `Setup` line. And yes, the break point does hit this line.

Comment: No that's not what I am talking about. Change it to a statement lambda or put it in another method so you can put a breakpoint at that exact line. Try `.Returns(() => { // Insert a line here Task.FromResult(httpResponse); });` and put a breakpoint right on `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as the return type is `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` instead of `Task<Func<HttpResponseMessage>>`... I tried the code you had and it's showing error

Comment: Use `.Returns( async () => ...`

Comment: No the break point doesn't hit the line. `.Returns(async ()  => new HttpResponseMessage
                               {
                                   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = content
                               });`

Comment: It hit this line after the getResponse() method was finished calling and the break point goes back to the method and hit that line when everything is finished..

Comment: @CodingYoshi any advise on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @superninja The provided code is incomplete and wont even compile. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @superninja How does `Request` relate to `HttpRequestMessage` that it can be used in the `Func<HttpRequestMessage>` like `()=>request` where `request` is `Request request`? Am I missing something in that code or is there a mistake in there

Comment: @superninja Firstly, the code you have posted does not compile. To get help, always make sure the posted code compiles. Secondly, once the compile errors are fixed, everything works and `httpResponseMessage` is not null. That means you are doing something you are not telling us and it is not being manifested in the posted code. If you care to see my sample which works, let me know and I will post it as an answer for you to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question appears to be lacking a complete explanation, the follow is being used for demonstrative purposes to show how to test the target method with moq.

Assuming the following

```
public interface IRetryHttpRequest {
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(Func<HttpRequestMessage> requestMessage, HttpClient client, int maxTryValue);
}

public class LibraryService : ILibraryService {
    private IRetryHttpRequest _retryHttpRequest;
    public LibraryService(IRetryHttpRequest retryHttpRequest) {
        _retryHttpRequest = retryHttpRequest;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseModel> GetResponseForSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest, HttpClient client) {
        //send request and retry if failed
        ResponseModel result = new ResponseModel();
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => new HttpRequestMessage(), client, 3);

        //process response
        if (httpResponseMessage != null) {
            string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public interface ILibraryService {

}
```

Note the syntax changes that would have shown errors with the original code shown in the question.

The following test demonstrates how to test the `LibraryService.GetResponse` method and assert the expected behavior

```
public async Task SampleTest() {
    //Arrange
    var content = new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage() {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = content
    };

    var _mockRetryHttpRequest = new Mock<IRetryHttpRequest>();
    _mockRetryHttpRequest
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<HttpRequestMessage>>(), It.IsAny<HttpClient>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(httpResponse);

    var lgService = new LibraryService(_mockRetryHttpRequest.Object);

    //Act
    var response = await lgService.GetResponseForSearch(new SearchRequest(), null);

    //Assert
    response.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

FluentAssertions was used to assert the expected behavior.

Some points to take note of

- Only the dependencies actually necessary for the test to be exercised to completion were provided to the subject under test. Which means no `HttpClient` is actually needed by the mock
- The method under test also needs to be awaited in order to get the response for assertion.
- Because I dont have access to your test data, I used an empty JSON object "{}" to represent the content of the response to allow the `JsonConvert` to work
- I would suggest then that you review your test data that is being deserialized. That may be the point of failure as that is the only place that the `result` can be set to `null` since it is being initialized at the top of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `response` variable is still returning null, which is really weird...

Comment: @superninja I tested this code and it works when run. Can up update your question with what is actually being done so I can reproduce your situation and find a solution.

Comment: @superninja I made the same changes to my test and it works as expected. The only difference with my test because I dont have access to your test data is that I used an empty JSON object `"{}"` to represent the content of the response and and allow the JsonConvert to work.

Comment: @superninja I would suggest then that you review your test data that is being deserialized. That may be the point of failure as that is the only place that the result can be set to null since it is being initialized at the top of the function.

Comment: interesting.. I don't thnk it's deserialization, cuz it's after getting the result of `httpResponseMessage`. I think my problem is more towards the `_retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync()` because it is giving `httpResponseMessage` a `null` value. The test result depends on `httpResponseMessage`..

Comment: @superninja I i get back a `HttpResponseMessage` with 200 OK and content.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have your test method async. Make it synchronous and then instead of awaiting, do the following:

```
var task = lgService.GetResponseForSearch(new SearchRequest(), null);

task.Wait();

var response = task.Result;

response.Should().NotBeNull();
```